# different RA/Decs returned by pyEphem

Tags: pyephem

I using pyEphem to calculate RA/Decs of satellites and I'm confused by the different
values computed and described on

http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/radec.html

this bit of code

```
sat=ephem.readtle("SATNAME ", \
              "1 38356U 12030A   14148.90924578  .00000000  00000-0  10000-3 0  5678",\
              "2 38356   0.0481  47.9760 0002933 358.9451 332.7970  1.00270012  3866")
gatech = ephem.Observer()
gatech.lon, gatech.lat = '-155.47322222', '19.82561111'
gatech.elevation = 4194
gatech.date = '2014/01/02 07:05:52'
sat.compute(gatech)
print 'a_ra=',sat.a_ra,'a_dec=',sat.a_dec,'g_ra=',sat.g_ra,'g_dec=',sat.g_dec,'ra=',sat.ra,'dec=',sat.dec
```

gives

a_ra= 0:52:40.75 a_dec= -3:15:23.7 g_ra= 1:14:10.55 g_dec= 0:06:09.8 ra= 0:53:23.57 dec= -3:10:50.5

if I change JUST the observers location to say
gatech.lon, gatech.lat = '-5.47322222', '19.82561111'

I get

a_ra= 1:15:36.95 a_dec= -2:32:29.9 g_ra= 1:14:10.55 g_dec= 0:06:09.8 ra= 1:16:19.75 dec= -2:28:04.6

I thought the observers position only came into the calculation of sat.ra and sat.dec
so was suprised to see a_ra and a_dec had changed.

What am I missing?

Thanks
Ad

Answer (score 2):

Per the last paragraph of the “body.compute(observer)” section of the Quick Reference:

http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/quick.html#body-compute-observer

> For earth satellite objects, the astrometric coordinates [meaning `a_ra` and `a_dec`] are topocentric instead of geocentric, since there is little point in figuring out where the satellite would appear on a J2000 (or whatever epoch you are using) star chart for an observer sitting at the center of the earth.

And in the issue that has been opened about this behavior, the project is open to suggestions about where this text can appear more prominently to prevent future confusion for users:

https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/pyephem/issues/55